# DataFrame dtypes to list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very wide dataframe, and I need the dtypes of all the columns as a list of dicts:

```
[{'name': 'col1', 'type': 'STRING'},...]
```

I need to do that to supply this as the schema for a BigQuery table.

How could that be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a comprehension:

```
out = [{'name': col, 'type': dtype.name} for col, dtype in df.dtypes.items()]
print(out)

# Output:
[{'name': 'col1', 'type': 'float64'}, {'name': 'col2', 'type': 'float64'}]
```